# How to construct a SparseMat from vectors OpenCV?

Tags: matlab, opencv, sparse-matrix

As in Matlab, I can initialize a sparse matrix from 3 vectors like

```html
Sparse = sparse(X,Y,Value,m,n);
```

Where X and Y are the indexes in the matrix, m and n are the required dimensions of the sparse mat.

Is there anything like this in OpenCV?

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dd/da9/classcv_1_1SparseMat.html

Comment: I've seen it, actually the idea behind asking here is to search for a solution